# valgrind does not show memory leak in log

Tags: c++, valgrind

I got a service, and running in my local, when I stopped the service, ASAN give me memory leak messages. So I tried to use Valgrind to find where it got leaked, but there is no such errors.

I run it with

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --verbose --log-file=out.txt /my/path/to/myshell -m myservice.py
```

"/my/path/to/myshell -m myservice.py" is the way to start my service in my local.

myshell invokes a Python customer interpreter with `os.execve`

and after I stopped my service, I see ASAN is giving me a lot of messages about memory leak, but in `out.txt`, I see the pid, which is the same process as I run `ps -ef`, but there is no memory leak info at all. where is wrong?

Comment: did you recompile without ASAN? did you compile with debugging?

Answer (score 2):

If you intend to run the program under valgrind, then don't compile with ASAN. They do not work together.

Recompile without `-fsanitize=address` and try again.

You also need the `--trace-children=yes` flag to valgrind in order for it to check subprocesses executed by `execve`.

Comment: I compiled without ASAN enabled, but still no output.

Comment: @code3 You probably also want to add the `--trace-children` flag to `valgrind` since it seems that your actual program is run only a few subprocesses down. You might want to put the `valgrind` call into the `os.execve` directly to avoid noise from the other processes.